# method to check the value does not work

Tags: c#

I want to do is, to check which value is bigger. At first, I ask (in the console) for the first value and for the second value. Than I want to check with the method "Bigger" which value is bigger. The problem is, that the method "Bigger" is underlined and I get an error.

Error:

> bigger_than ____ Input.Bigger ( bigger_than ____ Input . ) . " : Not all code paths return a value

Error comes from following method:

```
        public int Bigger(Input none)
        {
            if (First > none.Second) 
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (Second > none.First) 
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

---

Full Source Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace größer_als____
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int one;
            int two;

            Console.WriteLine("bigger than...");
            Console.WriteLine("one: ");
            Console.Write(">> ");
                one = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("two: ");
            Console.Write(">> ");
                two = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Input giveOne = new Input();
            giveOne.First = one;

            Input giveTwo = new Input();
            giveTwo.Second = two;

            if (giveOne.Bigger(giveTwo) == 1) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The first one [{0}] is bigger.", giveOne);
            }
            if(giveTwo.Bigger(giveOne) == -1) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The second one [{0}] is bigger.", giveTwo);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Input
    {
        private int first;

        public int First
        {
            get { return first;}
            set { first = value;}
        }

        private int second;

        public int Second
        {
            get { return second; }
            set { second = value; }
        }

        public int Bigger(Input none)
        {
            if (First > none.Second) 
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (Second > none.First) 
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get and where?

Comment: I get the error at the method "Bigger"

Comment: @echoteck: The first step in correcting an error is *reading the error*.

Comment: Which error do you get ? Describe the error the message that you are getting

Comment: This is the error: Error 1 " bigger_than ____ Input.Bigger ( bigger_than ____ Input . ) . " : Not all code paths return a value .

Comment: Despite of this, there is a reason to create an Input class?. From my point your code doesn't make much sense. It can be much simpler. For example am Input instance for every input, only filling one of it's properties.

Answer (score 4):

What if neither `if` ever hits? you need to provide a return for every possibility.

```
    public int Bigger(Input none)
    {
        if (First > none.Second) 
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (Second > none.First) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0; // <-- return something here
    }
```

Comment: okay thank you very much, I only have to return something.

Answer (score 1):

> Not all code paths return a value

What happens when you call `Bigger()` with two values that are equal?  It doesn't return anything.  Hence the error.

Add a default condition at the end:

```
public int Bigger(Input none)
{
    if (First > none.Second) 
        return 1;
    else if (Second > none.First) 
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, it woks now. You helped ma a lot!!!
Thank you very much!!!